# What do you call the -> operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

1. What do you call the `->` operator as in the following?

   ```
   ->(...) do
     ...
   end
   ```
2. Aren't the following snippets equivalent?

   ```
   succ = ->(x) {x + 1}
   succ = lambda {|x| x + 1}
   ```

Comment: It's annoying that you can't google "->" - good question to ask!

Comment: @Kevin you can, however, use Stack Overflow's built-in Elastic Search to search for `"->"`: [`title:"->" [ruby] is:question`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22-%3E%22+%5Bruby%5D+is%3Aquestion). The key is to use the quotation marks.

Comment: Symbolhound can also do this: http://symbolhound.com/?q=-%3E+ruby

Comment: annoying or not annoying, but googling for "ruby ->" request give link to this question as first top result.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

In *Ruby Programming Language* ("Methods, Procs, Lambdas, and Closures"), a lambda defined using `->` is called *lambda literal*.

```
succ = ->(x){ x+1 }
succ.call(2)
```

The code is equivalent to the following one.

```
succ = lambda { |x| x + 1 }
succ.call(2)
```

Informally, I have heard it being called *stabby lambda* or *stabby literal*.

Answer (score 142):

#### `=>` == **Hash Rocket**

Separates keys from values in a hash map literal.

---

#### `->` == **Dash Rocket**

Used to define a lambda literal in Ruby 1.9.X (without args) and Ruby 2.X (with args). The examples you give (`->(x) { x * 2 }` & `lambda { |x| x * 2 }`) are in fact equivalent.

Comment: FYI The 2 styles aren't fully interchangeable if you use `do`/`end` because of precedence rules. This prints an inspected lambda: `puts -> do 1 end`. This passes the block to `puts`, stealing it from the lambda and causing an ArgumentError: `puts lambda do 1 end`

Comment: Also, ruby 1.9.3's lambda literals do allow arguments.

Comment: @Kelvin that would be because Ruby tries to interpret `puts lambda do 1 end` as `puts(lambda) do 1 end` rather than `puts(lambda do 1 end)`. The latter does in fact work - Ruby just tries to pass the block to the `puts` method rather than the `lambda` method if there's no brackets.

Comment: @PJSCopeland I'm not saying you can't get them to act the same. I'm saying they aren't 100% interchangeable syntax-wise, i.e. you can't simply do a drop-in replacement in all cases (because sometimes you need extra parentheses for `lambda`).

Comment: @rdurand Did you make the edit with summary "Stabby lambdas cannot accept arguments in Ruby 1.9"? This is not accurate, at least for 1.9.3 - args are allowed.

Comment: beware of precedence rules (a counter example):
regrouping may be necessary, when interchanging lambda and dash rocket.

+1 on @Kelvin, I'll keep that in mind.

I wonder if there is a more elaborate blog for this like in this link: [Procs vs Lambdas](https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/library/how-lambdas-differ-from-procs-in-ruby)

Answer (score 5):

`->(x) { ... }` is the same as `lambda { |x| ... }`. It creates a lambda. See [Kernel#lambda](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda)  A lambda is a type of proc, one that ensures the number of parameters passed to it is correct. See also [Proc::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Proc.html#method-c-new) and [Kernel#proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-proc).