# Why we use "->" in queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations, model-associations, named-scope

I searched a lot but not found meaningful stuff,about why we use "->" in queries:

as in association:
 `has_many :comments, -> { order('posted_at DESC') }`

and in scopes:

```
scope :active, -> { where state: 'active' }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do you call Ruby's -> operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476627/what-do-you-call-rubys-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->` indicates lambda expression. You are forced to use this in scopes to prevent a kind of error possible in previous Rails version, when expression to use in scope was evaluated only once, when class was loaded. For example:

```
scope :today, where(date: Date.today)
```

This worked in Rails 3.x (I don't remember, but I think also in 4.0 and 4.1) and caused unexpected behavior, because `Date.today` was evaluated only once when the class was loaded. In prod environment this usually meant that `today` scope was returning records with `date` being equal to last deployment date. If you used lambda instead:

```
scope :today, -> { where(date: Date.today) }
```

the block passed into lambda is evaluated every time you call this scope.

Answer (score -1):

It is called lambda expression. Search for lambda functions in ruby.

To answer your question, you use lambda expression in this case, if you want to pass parameters to scope. It is not necessory though because you can have lambda function with 0 arity.

Comment: 1. The usage of lambdas are forced now. 2. Arity has nothing to do - look at my example - I don't pass any arguments also, but is different when I use lambda.