# `->` operator with scopes

Tags: ruby, lambda, literals

What is the `->` operator in the following?

```
scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
```

`scope` is a method, `:published` is a symbol passed as an argument, which leads me to believe that `-> { where(published: true) }` makes up the next argument. `->` is not a valid method name due to the presence of the `>` character.

Comment: Google for ruby lambda operator

Comment: It is called 'lambda literal' or 'stabby lambda'. It's just a way of creating a lamda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called lambda literal, and is just a short way of creating a lamda. Following are same:

```
double = -> (x) { 2 * x }
double.call(10) # => 20
```

is equivalent to:

```
double = lambda {|x| 2 * x }
double.call(10) # => 20
```

Incase you're not familiar with lambdas, then checkout ruby-doc for more details http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F

Also, checkout following StackOverflow thread [What do you call the -> operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476627/what-do-you-call-rubys-operator)