# Ruby or Rails array iteration syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, iteration

I came across a way in which a program extracted the `name` property of an object and found the syntax a little peculiar. This is dealing with the results of JSON response.

Our JSON response would be the following =

```
[{"id"=>9, "name"=>"Baked Potato w/ Cheese", "instructions"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>12, "name"=>"Baked Brussel Sprouts", "instructions"=>nil}]

results = JSON.parse(response.body)

def extract_name
  ->(object) { object["name"] }
end

results.map(&extract_name)
```

So I understand that `results.map(&extract_name)` returns the `name` of the JSON objects, I just don't understand how.

I'm unfamiliar with the `->(object) { object["name"] }` syntax. Are there are other shorthand ways of doing this that may help me get a better idea of this type of syntax?

Comment: @sschmeck's answer is good, but it's worth noting that this isn't great code. This code initializes a new lambda every time `extract_name` is called. It would be better to assign the lambda to a variable or constant, e.g. `EXTRACT_NAME = ->(object) { object["name"] }; results.map(&EXTRACT_NAME)`.

Comment: @Jordan: Are you sure about that? I'm pretty sure that `e.map(&m)` will be parsed as `e.map(&(m()))` so `m` will only be called once and then `&` will be applied to its return value only once.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but what I wrote is "This code initializes a new lambda every time `extract_name` is called." It won't be called for every iteration, but it will be called every time `results.map(&extract_name)` is called.

Comment: @Jordan So if I were to write two test's each one running the `results.map(&extract_name)`, I will be initializing two lambdas as opposed to just setting it to a constant where it is only initialized once? To my understanding, this is more efficient yes?

Comment: @Jordan Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow `->` is a short syntax to create lambas. See "[What do you call the -> operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476627/what-do-you-call-the-operator-in-ruby)".

An alternative way could be the following snippet:

```
results.map { |object| object["name"] }
```

Comment: `object[:name]` should be `object["name"]` for equivalence with OP's code.