# How do I use loops?

Tags: ruby, loops, shoes

I am programming a little game with Ruby/Shoes. I am trying to get this code into a loop. It should repeat after the last timer. I don't know how to start with this.

```
@timer2= timer(20)do
  @pic.move(100,170)
end

@timer2= timer(40) do
  @pic.move(350,120)
end

@timer2= timer(60) do
  @pic.move(20,400)
end

@timer2= timer(80) do
  @pic.move(420,60)
end
```

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you add some `timer()` code that explains this part of your design

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does this have to do with Rails? Is this code part of a webservice? A model? A controller? A view? A helper?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop your code:

```rb
loop {
  @timer2 = timer(20) do
    @pic.move(100, 170)
  end

  @timer2 = timer(40) do
    @pic.move(350, 120)
  end

  @timer2 = timer(60) do
    @pic.move(20, 400)
  end

  @timer2 = timer(80) do
    @pic.move(420, 60)
  end
}
```

Use `break` if you need to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example to try timer in loops

```
class Picture
  def initialize
    @last_move = {}
  end

  def move(x, y)
    @last_move = { x: x, y: y }
    puts @last_move
  end

  def self.test_movement
    @pic = new
    pic_moves = [
      { t: 2, x: 100, y: 170 },
      { t: 4, x: 350, y: 120 },
      { t: 6, x: 20, y: 400 },
      { t: 3, x: 420, y: 60 }
    ]
    pic_moves.each do |pm|
      sleep(pm[:t])
      puts(pm[:t])
      @pic.move(pm[:x], pm[:y])
    end
  end
end

Picture.test_movement
```

Comment: Can you explain the first part? What does pm, o and t stand for?

Comment: I just declared Proc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538513/4453714

Comment: Ok, I ll add explanation to answer, but add some info about timer - what should it do? wait for executing next code in seconds?

Comment: Yes it should just wait..

Comment: Check please updated example, I don't advice to use exactly this one, but it should work, i suggest

Comment: I will try it thank you!

Comment: to try first timer example(with puts) you can do something like 
`[1, 3, 4].each { |s| timer.call(s) }`

Comment: You know, I just made example for you overcomplicated. Now I ve try to do simle file that work and maybe do what you need. so I ll update all answer